# How to make JPA EntityListeners validate the existence of an interface

Tags: jpa, entitylisteners

I am working in J2EE 5 using JPA, I have a working solution but I'm looking to clean up the structure.

I am using EntityListeners on some of the JPA objects I am persisting, the listeners are fairly generic but depend on the beans implementing an interface, this works great if you remember to add the interface.

I have not been able to determine a way to tie the EntityListener and the Interface together so that I would get an exception that lead in the right direction, or even better a compile time error.

```
@Entity
@EntityListener({CreateByListener.class})
public class Note implements CreatorInterface{
    private String message;....
    private String creator;
    ....
}

public interface CreatorInterface{
    public void setCreator(String creator);
}

public class CreateByListener {
    @PrePersist
    public void dataPersist(CreatorInterface data){
        SUser user = LoginModule.getUser();
        data.setCreator(user.getName());
    }
}
```

This functions exactly the way I want it to, except when a new class is created and it uses the CreateByListener but does not implement the CreatorInterface.
When this happens a class cast exception is thrown somewhere deep from within the JPA engine and only if I happen to remember this symptom can I figure out what went wrong.

I have not been able to figure a way to require the interface or test for the presence of the interface before the listener would be fired.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
@PrePersist
public void dataPersist(Object data){
    if (!(data instanceof CreatorInterface)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The class " 
                                           + data.getClass() 
                                           + " should implement CreatorInterface");
    }
    CreatorInterface creatorInterface = (CreatorInterface) data;
    SUser user = LoginModule.getUser();
    creatorInterface.setCreator(user.getName());
}
```

This does basically the same thing as what you're doing, but at least you'll have a more readable error message indicating what's wrong, instead of the ClassCastException.